# How to count the number of high voltages in Hantek Oscilloscope?

Tags: oscilloscope, high-voltage, counter, waveform

I have a Hantek 6022BE oscilloscope and I want to know how I can count the time and number of times a certain voltage is reached by the wave. For example, I am measuring the voltage of data being transferred over a USB cable. So since the data is transferred as 1s and 0s, the voltage is **approximately** either high (around 20mV) or low (0V). I want to know how many high voltage (around 20mV) spikes there are. Obviously since there is a lot of noise, the electrical signal of the waveform is not very clean.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

I want to know if there is a way to count for how long the voltage was above a certain, manually set, voltage. Can the Hantek application which I downloaded do this for me in any way?

Comment: 20mV on USB?  Something is broken or you aren't connecting it correctly.  Maybe the time base is set too low.

Comment: USB 2.0 Data is at 200MHz.  Your scope doesn't have the bandwidth needed to count the pulses, regardless of whether the software has a function for it.  This is also why you are only seeing 20mV.  The data is far outside the bandwidth, and you are seeing aliasing artifacts of whatever gets through the filters.

Comment: @JRE The probe is connected to the D+ wire of the USB cable, not the power (+5V).

Comment: @JRE But how come I am able to see the waveforms? I have edited my question, look at the screenshots

Comment: @JRE I have added 2 screenshots now

Comment: You should be seeing peaks of 2.8V measured from ground on the D+ and D- lines.  You aren't seeing that because your scope has a bandwidth of 20MHz, but USB 2.0 is at 200MHz.  This is like trying to hear an ultrasonic dog whistle with your ears - you ears can't handle signals that high, and your scope won't handle signals as fast as USB 2.0

Comment: Even worse.  I see now that your sample rate is 8MHz.  With that, you can view signals upto 4MHz.  That's 1/50 of the sampling rate you would need.  Your scope simply can't do what you want from it.

Comment: @JRE Then what is it that I am seeing?

Comment: See the latest edit to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

With the additional data you've now posted, the answer is simple:

You cannot.

The bandwidth of your scope is not up to the task of viewing a USB2.0 signal.

USB2.0 runs at 200MHz, and your scope has a bandwidth of (at best) 20MHz ([See the Hantek site for the model 6022BE](http://www.hantek.com/en/ProductDetail_2_31.html).)

Whether the PC software for the scope is capable of counting the pulses (or not) is pretty much irrelevant, since the scope isn't capable of capturing the USB signal.

You need to look up bandwidth, sampling, shannon's theory, aliasing, and antialiasing filters.

---

The areas I've marked in red should be bursts of data.  The smaller area marked in blue would be a shorter data burst.  In both cases, you should see a bunch of 2.8Volt peaks, but you only have 20mV.

You are not seeing the data itself, only smeared mush that tells you "there may have been data here."

When data is present, there would be something like 200 peaks in 1 square on your scope (set for 10µS per square.)

[image]

For comparison, here is a good image of USB data captured with a Tetronix scope (from [the Tektronix site](http://www.tek.com/datasheet/mso5000-dpo5000-series)):

[image]

Comment: So are all these bursts of data just where the actual data is? It has just been scaled down to fit the specs of my oscilloscope? Wherever there are the bursts should be the location of the data right?

Comment: It hasn't been scaled down to fit the specs of your scope.  The data wasn't captured at all.  Just a mush of garbage that is a side effect of the scope not being able to handle the signal.  Where there are bursts in your picture, there probably should have been data.  It may also just be noise on the USB lines.  There's nothing really useful you can tell looking at your images except "well, there's something going on."

Comment: But it can't be noise because when I disconnect the probe from USB cable, the waveform I am currently getting goes away. So could I just assume that where there are the bursts, there is data? If not, is there any other way I can get the results I am looking for?

Comment: Which Hantek Oscilloscope should I use instead? I might have to buy one unless it's too expensive.

Comment: Do you think analogue oscilloscopes are capable of capturing the waveform? Sorry for so many questions and thank you for being so patient.

Comment: You would only see useful data on an analog scope if (1) you have one with super high bandwidth (unlikely) and (2) you can configure the USB device in a 'test mode' where it outputs alternating signals on D+ and D- specifically for testing (usually with high-end DSOs capable of applying the USBIF-mandated eye diagram). You really need a high-bandwidth DSO and special measurement techniques to not overly burden the differential bus.

Comment: If you stick with Hantek, you would need at least a [DSO3254](http://www.hantek.com/en/ProductDetail_2_134.html)  That is an absolute minimum.  I expect you will need an even faster scope to really do any good.  Check with the supplier before buying to see if the software can do the counting you require.

Comment: That is very much a minimum.  You probably ought to check the products from more well known companies like Tektronix or LeCroy.

Comment: Or Agilent/Keysight

Comment: @AdamLawrence How can I configure my USB device to test mode? What exactly will happen with that and will that enable me to use my current Hantek Oscilloscope to get a waveform of the data transfer?

Comment: It won't let you do anything useful with your Hantek 6022BE.  That will let you do a very (minimal) test of the USB signal quality on an analog scope (eye test.)

Comment: @LakshyaGoyal Depends on your device. Microchip parts have a SFR bit for this mode, for instance. And it won't help for your current solution.

Comment: @AdamLawrence So is there no way for me to do my investigation to find the waveforms and count the time of the high voltages?

Comment: Not with your existing setup, no.